# Pandas compare values for the same time every day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame:

```
date_time           value
1/10/2016  0:00:00  28.4 
1/10/2016  0:05:00  28.4
1/10/2016  0:10:00  28.4
1/11/2016  0:00:00  27.4
1/11/2016  0:05:00  27.4
1/11/2016  0:10:00  27.4
```

I want to calculate the difference between two rows in the same timestamp everyday, then add new calculated data to a new column like this:

```
date_time           value  change24h
1/10/2016  0:00:00  28.4   NaN
1/10/2016  0:05:00  28.4   NaN
1/10/2016  0:10:00  28.4   NaN
1/11/2016  0:00:00  27.4   -1
1/11/2016  0:05:00  29.4   +1
1/11/2016  0:10:00  28.4   0
```

I don't want to add new column with last day data then calculate the change. Is there other way for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#convert column to datetime and create index
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date_time']))
#shift by 1 day and reindex for same indices, subtract from right by rsub
df['change24h'] = df['value'].shift(freq='1D').reindex(df.index).rsub(df['value'])
#same as
#df['change24h'] = df['value'].sub(df['value'].shift(freq='1D').reindex(df.index))
#remove datetime index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
           date_time  value  change24h
0  1/10/2016 0:00:00   28.4        NaN
1  1/10/2016 0:05:00   28.4        NaN
2  1/10/2016 0:10:00   28.4        NaN
3  1/11/2016 0:00:00   27.4       -1.0
4  1/11/2016 0:05:00   29.4        1.0
5  1/11/2016 0:10:00   28.4        0.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day